# chef - Re-raising exception TypeError - can't convert nil into String

Tags: windows, chef-infra, chef-recipe

Hi I am getting started on using chef on windows and have followed the [quickstart guide](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Fast+Start+Guide+for+Windows#FastStartGuideforWindows-Step5%253AConfiguretheworkstationasaclient). I am using chef-solo and got it working with the getting started cookbook where it just writes a template out to the home directory, but any cookbook which installs something I get the error "Re-raising exception TypeError - can't convert nil into String" with no indication where the problem is.

I have my chef repo [here on github](https://github.com/henryoswald/windows-chef-spike/tree/3b027c03331088516f3d96cb666ffb50d42e7896) which is trying to install 7-zip.

I have tried running with -l debug and [this is the full stach trace](http://pastebin.com/eNp7Jy5d).

I am a bit at a loss now of how to find the nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Chef are you using?
I had a similar problem with Chef **0.10.10** on Ubuntu.

To solve this I upgraded my Chef version. In my case I ran

```
sudo gem update chef
```

Now I have 10.14.2 and everything is fine.

Not sure how you have configured your Windows install but you can try to run it without the sudo in front.